# Server calculations with ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing some small asp.net core application with EF and I have a problem. I want server to do some work and than update database every 20 seconds. So I have some class with constructor that looks like this:

```
public UpdateStocks(ILogger<UpdateStocks> logger, IRepository<Stock> stockRepository,
                   IRepository<Product> productRepository, IRepository<DatedPrice> priceRepository)
       {
           this.stockRepository = stockRepository;
           this.productRepository = productRepository;
           this.priceRepository = priceRepository;           
           timer1 = new Timer();
           timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick);
           timer1.Interval = 20000; // in miliseconds
           timer1.Start();
       }
```

As far as I understand this right, this doesn't concern MVC at all and I should write separete logic for this task. But I'm already have DbContext in services plus logger and other stuff like repository classes.

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
services.AddScoped<IRepository<Product>, SQLProductRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IRepository<Stock>, SQLStockRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IRepository<DatedPrice>, SQLDatedPriceRepository>();
```

Should I use different connection to database, logger and repo instances for this logic or I can somehow import them from services? Where should I create an instance of `UpdateStocks` class? Program.cs?  What is the right way to do this? Sorry if the question is stupid or the answer is obvious, I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: You can't do a repetitive task from a web request context. You need to either create a separate windows service which does this task on a schedule, or you might be able to use something like Hangfire which adds long running job functionality into your existing asp.net application